# Using std::ref, content does not change after exiting function

Tags: c++, multithreading, reference-wrapper, strassen

I have been implementing Strassen algorithm with threads. I have passed data to threads by structures and launching them by function `pthread_create()` . The problem is I'm operating on     `std::vector < std::vector<int> >`     and I can't pass this to structure by reference. I have done some research and decided to     use `std::ref`     to wrap content and send it to function. The problem begins after exiting the function; r1 value does not change (inside changes), so there is something incorrect.

Example code:

```
typedef struct threadData
{
    int n;
    std::vector< std::vector<int> > mat1;
    std::vector< std::vector<int> > mat2;
    std::vector< std::vector<int> > result;
}thread_Data;



/* function adding 2 matrixes */

void *add_Thread(void *arg)
{
    thread_Data *data = (threadData*)arg;
    for (int i = 0; i < data->n; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < data->n; ++j)
        {
            data->result[i][j] = data->mat1[i][j] + data->mat2[i][j];
        }
    }

    pthread_exit(0);
}

/* ... code ... */

thread_Data adds;
adds = thread_Data{newSize, a11, a22, std::ref(r1)};  // here passing by std::ref

pthread_t adder;

pthread_create(&adder, NULL, add_Thread, &adds[i]);

pthread_join(adder, NULL);

/* and r1 value does not change here */
```

How to fix it?

NOTE: *add_Thread() works fine; I use array in my program. The code here is only to show idea.

Comment: `std::ref` doesn't magically make a non-reference a reference. `thread_Data::result` is not a reference. Also note that `typedef struct` is not required in C++. Just use `struct thread_Data`. I'm also not sure `&adds[i]` is doing what you think it's doing... `adds` is not an array.

Comment: Any reason you aren't using `std::thread`?  It knows about `std::reference_wrapper`'s and handles them correctly.

Comment: Yes it is not an array here. But in my program is. I just wanted to do a shortcut

Comment: @NathanOliver I'm beginner in threads

Comment: That's even more of a reason to use `std::thread`.  It works with the type system, so no void pointers and casting has to be done.

Comment: @NathanOliver sure, I have to try it. But this is the only problem that bothers me. If I fix it, my project would be finished. Using std::thread I have to do too much work for now. But if nothing helps, I will do it.

Comment: @cdhowie so is here any way to deal with passing r1 to structure? Changing variable result type to reference? :d

Comment: @kjtn99 You could simply make `result` a pointer.

Comment: @cdhowie I'm confused. Pointers are not my favourite things :D. New type should be std::vector< std::vector<int> > * ?

Comment: @kjtn99 Yes. If you are going to assign one `thread_Data` object to another then you can't use references as they can't be reseated.

Comment: @cdhowie Then what should I change in loop in function adding matrixes? Types will be different

Comment: @kjtn99 For simpler access, after `thread_Data *data = (threadData*)arg;` you could add `auto & result = *(data->result);` then just use `result` instead of `data->result` everywhere else.

Comment: 2) error: cannot convert ‘std::reference_wrapper<std::vector<std::vector<int> > >’ to ‘std::vector<std::vector<int> >*’ in initialization
   adds[0] = thread_Data{newSize, a11, a22, std::ref(r1)};

Comment: @kjtn99 Of course, because `std::ref` isn't appropriate there (which we already said). Use `&r1`.

Comment: Oh man, dummy me. Everything works. Thank You bro !!

Comment: @kjtn99 No problem!